# Not able to set state in react properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous, async-await

I have this function which is setting the user

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

  const getUser = async () => {
    setIsAuth(false)
    setLoading(true)
    try {
      let temp = await axiosURL.get('/api/users/me')
      temp = temp.data
      if (temp) {
        setUser(temp)
        setIsAuth(true)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    setLoading(false)
  }
```

After setting the user I am fecthing the data acording to the user

```
   const getAllScopeData = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    await getUser()
    console.log(user)
    await getScopeOneData()
    await getScopeTwoData()
    await getScopeThreeData()
    setLoading(false)
  }
```

But when I am running `getAllScopeData()` The user details is fetching correctly and logging in the console but `user` from the state is not changing from null . So I am able to fetch further data .

Comment: You can't get the state variable after calling the setter function. That's, you call `setUser()` in `getUser()`, then print `console.log(user)`. React state setter function works asynchronously. So you can't get the correct value. Need to use `useEffect` to get the changed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem I see it's here

```
const getAllScopeData = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    await getUser()
    console.log(user)
    await getScopeOneData()
    await getScopeTwoData()
    await getScopeThreeData()
    setLoading(false)
  }
```

even if you wait for the function `getUser` your state is not update yet

You should use `useEffect` like this

```
useEffect(async() => {
if(!user) return;
   setLoading(true)
    await getScopeOneData()
    await getScopeTwoData()
    await getScopeThreeData()
    setLoading(false)
}, [user])
```